# Android Arraylist<String[]> always follow the value of a String[] variable

Tags: android, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList. I read text file from Android phone and store String[3] in each array. I used the debugger to trace the value of each variable. **The value in ArrayList seem like always follow the value of buffer.** Is it any link between them?

```
ArrayList<String[]> label_list = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(getPath());
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    String[] buffer = new String[3];
    int j=0;
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!aDataRow.equals("")){
            buffer[j]=aDataRow;
            j++;
        }else{
            label_list.add(buffer);
            j=0;
        }
    }
    label_list.add(buffer); //for last one
    myReader.close();
    for(int i=0;i<label_list.size();i++){
        txt_show.append(label_list.get(i)[0]);
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The text file i read.

[image: The text file i read]

The result of debugger. As you can see, all arrays have same value. The value in Arraylist will always follow the value of buffer.

[image: As you can see, all arrays have same value]

Answer (score 0):

You must put that `j++` out of `if else` condition.

```
ArrayList<String[]> label_list = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(getPath());
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    String[] buffer = new String[3];
    int j=0;
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!aDataRow.equals("")){
            buffer[j]=aDataRow;

        }else{
            label_list.add(buffer);

        }
            j++;
    }
    label_list.add(buffer); //for last one
    myReader.close();
    for(int i=0;i<label_list.size();i++){
        txt_show.append(label_list.get(i)[0]);
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I have tried but no luck. Actually during debugging, I could see all the thing work fine except label_list.add(buffer). It will overwrite the earlier value. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. Add **buffer = new String[3];** will solve my problem but I do not know why. Can anyone explain to me?

```
try {
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(getPath());
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    String[] buffer = new String[3];
    int j=0;
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!aDataRow.equals("")){
            buffer[j]=aDataRow;
            j++;
        }else{
            label_list.add(buffer);
            j=0;
            **buffer = new String[3];**
        }
    }
    myReader.close();
    for(int i=0;i<label_list.size();i++){
        txt_show.append(label_list.get(i)[0]);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```